# Using ahk setting windows +arrow keys

Tags: autohotkey

I am using AutoHotKey and I'm trying to set the up arrow key to up arrow key + left windows key, and the down arrow key to down arrow key + down arrow key.  This way I can press a single key to maximize and minimize a window in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Really should try and post some code as to what you have tried but this should get you what you asked for. If Up arrow is pressed it will send Win+Up then same for the down.

```
UP::
Send,  #{up}
return

Down::
Send, #{down}
return
```

However this is not the best solution for what you are trying to do. AHK has built in functions for handling windows in this way. Below the code will minimize the active window while checking that a window is active and you are not on the desktop (needed based on quick testing). Then it will also store the window it minimizes in the `OldWin` var so that the up command can restore the window you last minimized.

```
Up::
WinRestore , %OldWin%
return


Down::
WinGetActiveTitle, OldWin
if OldWin!= 
    {
    WinMinimize, A 
    }
return
```

Comment: I got it to work with this far simpler script:

$Up::#Up 

Thanks anyway.